# The system class loader's resource lookup algorithm

Tags: java, android

In Java [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) I see such statements:

> The system class loader's resource
>   lookup algorithm is used to find the
>   resource.

But where can I learn how this "lookup algorithm" actually works, especially in context of Android.

Answer (score 6):

you have a hierarchy of class loaders in java, e.g.:

```
    Bootstrap CL
        |
        |
    Extension CL
        |
        |
SystemClassLoader CL
        |
        |    
Application Specific CL
```

When invoking a CL's findClass() Method a ClassLoader normally delegates to it's parent first which will try to load the Class.

E.g. if you're trying to load a Class which is in the **ext-folder** of your JVM you could use

```
Class clazz=ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().findClass("org.pack.ExtClass");
```

this will first delegate to it's parent, the Extension ClassLoader, which will delegate to it's parent, the Bootstrap CL. The Bootstrap CL will return null to the Extension ClassLoader since it could not find the class, then the Extension CL will look for the Class on it's own. Since it will find the class "org.pack.ExtClass" in the classpath it will load, prepare and return the class to the SystemClassLoader, which will set the reference `clazz` to the returned class object.

So as a general rule a ClassLoader will always delegate to it's parent first and the try to find the class on it's own.

But there are Exceptions to this rule, the most prominent being the WebApp Classloaders of Tomcat et al. where the WebAppClassLoader behaves a bit differently. I think there's a bootstrap.jar in the Tomcat Directory with a CL which will load classes first and only delegate to it's parent if the requested class could not be found.

Some Links:

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2248831/Java-Class-Loading-The-Basics.htm

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/

hope that helped..

Answer (score 2):

In Android (Dalvik) system classloader is [PathClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/PathClassLoader.html).

You will have to look at its source code to figure out the algo. It would be a some form of tree traversal across available Jar files and directories.